# mySQL SELECT Left Outer Join involving more than 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

Given the following tables:

> Students((PK)studentID, firstName, lastName, gender, dateOfBirth)
>
> Courses((PK)courseCode, courseName, classLevel, credit)
>
> Registration((PK,FK)studentID, (PK,FK)courseCode, grade)

I'd like to write a query that grabs the info for every student (**Students.studentID**, **Students.firstName**, **Students.lastName**), their course info (**Courses.courseName**), and grade (**Registration.grade**), including students who *aren't registered for classes* returning null values in the courseName and grade columns for those students.

From what I know (I'm still learning a lot) this will require something like:

`Students LEFT OUTER JOIN [some aggregate of Courses and Registration]`

But I'm not sure how to format it using mySQL syntax.

Here what I've got:

```
SELECT S.studentID, S.firstName, S.lastName, C.courseName, R.grade
    FROM Courses AS C, Students AS S
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Registration AS R ON S.studentID = R.studentID
    AND R.courseCode = C.courseCode
ORDER BY S.studentID
;
```

I know its not right I get a 'Unknown Column C.courseCode' error, so the syntax is obviously off, but this is as close as I could get to what I think it needs to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `left join`, start with table that contains all the rows you want to keep.  In this case, `students`.  Then use `left join` on all the other tables.

Also, *never* use commas in the `from` clause.  *Always* use explicit `join` syntax.

So, your query should look like:

```
SELECT S.studentID, S.firstName, S.lastName, C.courseName, R.grade
FROM Students S LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Registration R
     ON S.studentID = R.studentID LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Courses AS C, 
     ON R.courseCode = C.courseCode
ORDER BY S.studentID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still trying to segregate my work in SQL from my years of background in C (which is constantly screwing me up). This worked perfectly.

Is there any difference between when and when not to use "AS" when establishing aliases? Is it just preference like when to indent etc

Comment: "Optional. Most programmers will specify the AS keyword when aliasing a column name, but not when aliasing a table name." (See http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need? (I prefer `LEFT JOIN` because it is shorter than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but they are the same.)

```
SELECT S.studentID, S.firstName, S.lastName, C.courseName, R.grade
    FROM Students AS S
    LEFT JOIN Registration AS R ON S.studentID = R.studentID
    LEFT JOIN Courses AS C ON R.courseCode = C.courseCode
ORDER BY S.studentID
;
```

Edit: Like Gordon, I prefer explicit joins as you can see from my answer. However, to my knowledge there is no difference in performance.